# Logrus timestamp with millisecond

Tags: go, logging

With the latest version of `logrus` (v1.4.2), I'm not able to set the millisecond/microsecond in the log formatter.

With the previous version (I don't remember which), I simply use the following time format:

```golang
Formatter := new(log.TextFormatter)
Formatter.TimestampFormat = "15-01-2018 15:04:05.000000"
Formatter.FullTimestamp = true
Formatter.ForceColors = true
log.SetFormatter(Formatter)
log.SetLevel(log.DebugLevel)
```

Unfortunately, with the latest version, seems that this timestamp format is no more allowed.
When I try to print a line with the above time format, I receive the following result:
`17-11-7118 17:35:46.314715`

Instead of the correct one:
`7-11-2019 17:35:46.314715`

Does someone know how to configure `Logrus` for print the timestamp with a *microsecond/millisecond* precision?

Comment: Your format string is invalid. It doesn't use the proper [reference time](https://golang.org/pkg/time/#pkg-constants).

Comment: I also fail to see how this relates at all to milliseconds. Your milliseconds are working perfectly.

Comment: Thank you for the solution. As you can see, the first it is not correct if I set that particular time format (17-11-7118 instead of 7-11-2019)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As pointed by @Flimzy, the time format that i was using was not valid.

I've fixed using the following time format `2006-01-02T15:04:05.999999999Z07:00`.

Another (more human) timestamp format can be the following: `Jan _2 15:04:05.000000000`

For more example about the time format, refer here -> https://golang.org/pkg/time/#pkg-constants